# How to get the difference of two consecutive rows and same column in MySQL and save it to different column in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, difference

```
binmin  binmax  value   diff
-0.5    0.499   20      
0.5     1.499   30      10
1.5     2.499   45      15
2.5     3.499   56      11
```

I want to take the difference of values ie. current - previous.
the binmin and binmax are already in order and keep on increasing.
you can use binmin or binmax as id.
I want to take the difference and insert it into another empty column called diff!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite?  Tag appropriately.

Comment: Its MySQL!
Sorry for not mentioning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the previous value in MySQL/SQLite can be done with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (value -
        (select t2.value
         from testtable t2
         where t2.binmin < t.binmin
         order by t2.binmin desc
         limit 1
        )
       ) as diff
from testtable t;
```

Comment: What is your table name here?
assuming there is only one table ie.testtable //Assuming

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?